# Why can I return a recursive run of promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following code (reconstructed almost 1:1 to work in here):

First of all, understand that `bridge_component_start_test` is really a call to a constructor object where we generate the initial promise by `return new Promise..` I tried to mimick this here. It's my factory for AJAX calls, so, each object creates a promise, which makes a call, which then resolves / rejects with the JSON that it received from the server. I've emulated that response in the resolves below as well.

```js
function recursive_function(data) {
  let local_data = $.extend({}, data);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //The offset gets
    local_data.bridge_process_batch_offset++;
    if (local_data.bridge_process_batch_offset == 3) {
      resolve({
        'data': {
          'response_data': {
            'done_batching': true
          }
        },
        'success': true
      })
    } else {
      resolve({
        'data': {
          'response_data': {
            'done_batching': false,
            'bridge_process_batch_offset': local_data.bridge_process_batch_offset
          }
        },
        'success': true
      })
    }
    //For now, no reject.
  });
}

function do_the_main_thing(data) {
  /**
   * Make a local copy of the passed data.
   */
  let request_data = $.extend({}, data);

  let bridging_data = {
    'just_installed_component_demo': request_data.just_installed_component_demo,
    'just_installed_component_name': request_data.just_installed_component_name,
    'just_installed_component_category': request_data.just_installed_component_category,
    'bridge_process_batch_offset': 0
  };

  const recursively_do_things = () => recursive_function(bridging_data).then(response => {
    if (response.data.response_data.done_batching) {
      return (response);
    } else if (response.data.success == false) {
      return response;
    } else {
      console.log('Went through step ' + response.data.response_data.bridge_process_batch_offset + '!');
      if ('bridge_process_batch_offset' in response.data.response_data) {
        bridging_data.bridge_process_batch_offset = response.data.response_data.bridge_process_batch_offset;
      }
      return recursively_do_things ();
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    return error;
  });

  return recursively_do_things();
}

do_the_main_thing({
  'just_installed_component_demo': 'demo-2',
  'just_installed_component_name': 'demo-2_post',
  'just_installed_component_category': 'post',
  'bridge_process_batch_offset': 0
}).then(response => {
  console.log('...and now I am done!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But notice, in my `do_the_main_thing` I'm merely returning the `response` from that promise recursion. Yes, surely, I also `return recursively_bridge_component_start` but how does JS know to return a promise out of that recursive functionality?

A return is a return. It doesn't have to wait for the Promise to finish, yet it seems it does. In theory, my last line of `return recursively_do_things` should just instantly return before the Promises are done.

What am I missing here?

Comment: This would be easier to comprehend with shorter function names which aren't all almost exactly alike…

Comment: I agree @deceze it takes already lots of time to simply scroll up and down to understand anything from it ^_^

Comment: @deceze I'll do an edit but it's hard since I need to emulate the response from the server.

Comment: @deceze Updated mine, as well as everyone's details in regards to the new function names.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning merely `response` from `recursively_do_things`

If you look at the function, you are returning a part of the chain, your `return response` is just part of the promise chain.

So this part

```
const recursively_do_things= () => recursive_function(bridging_data).then(response => /* omitted */ );
```

is returning you a promise chain implying that it first waits for `recursive_function` to complete, and `then` does the inner response, after which you can chain other statements

so, since you are returning `return recursively_do_things()` from your `do_the_main_thing(data)`, it is clear that a promise will be returned.

#### Update based on comment

Promises are promise aware themselves, which means that if you return a promise in a chain, the promise chain will wait for the returned promise to complete before continuing the next part of the chain.

The requirement for that is that you need to return it, if you just call a function that returns a promise, it will not wait for it.

Comment: Alright, I forgot to mention, my problem was with, what if, inside this return, I start another Promise chain? Does the "mother" wait for the child chain to stop?

Comment: @coolpasta it does, as long as you return it, if you just start it, it won't wait, you have to return the promise

Answer (score 0):

But it's quite straightforward. The return value of `bridge_component_start_in_test(data)` is the return value of `recursively_bridge_component_start()`.

That function in turn returns `bridge_component_start_test(data).then(/* do stuff */).catch(/* do other stuff */)`. That will always be a promise regardless of details of "do stuff" and "do other stuff".

And `bridge_component_start_test` explicitely returns a promise: `return new Promise(//...`

Comment: (Copy from the other answer) Alright, I forgot to mention, my problem was with, what if, inside this return, I start another Promise chain? Does the "mother" wait for the child chain to stop?